# Asterisk регистрация sip транк софт от Huawei

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Есть софт от локального оператора на Huawei, софт прописан под маркетинговый бранд и название так и не нашел. Хочу зарегистрировать SIP транк на астериске.

Данные которые содержатся в софте следующие:

```
Login Server: 76.45.65.40 port 5060
Domain: ims.korektel.com
Group Server IP:76.45.60.22 port 9190
Proxy Server addres: 76.45.60.22 port 9190
```

ну и собственно `username:07503695859 password:XXXXXXX`

На Астериске я прописал:

```
register =>07503695859:XXXXXXX:07503695859@korek/07503695859

[korek]
type=friend
username=07503695859
secret=XXXXXXX
dtmfmode=rfc2833
host=76.45.65.40
context=incoming
outboundproxy=76.45.60.22
port=9190
fromuser=07503695859
fromdomain=ims.korektel.com
usereqphone=yes
canreinvite=no
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
-- Registration for '07503695859@korek' timed out, trying again (Attempt #7)
```

Пытаюсь позвонить – тоже ничего.

После регистрации заметил, что в софте указан номер `9647503695859`, но при вводе *username* и *password*, *username* выводится `07503695859`.

Позвонил оператору – они не знают и рекомендуют использование их софта.

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Попробуйте вот такую строку регистрации:

```
register => 9647503695859@ims.korektel.com:XXXXXX:"9647503695859@ims.korektel.com"@76.45.65.40/korek
```

**Обновление**

в Беларуси местный монополист стационарной телефонии предоставляет услуги связи как раз на платформе ims от huawei. Так вот методом долгих чаяний была выведена строка регистрации именно в таком формате. Т.е. это рабочий вариант.

Comment: Регистрацыя есть но звонок не проходет, что у себя в пере указал?

Answer (score 1):

SIP - текстовый протокол. Натравите Wireshark на их самопальный софт, посмотрите процесс регистрации и сравните с тем, что делает Asterisk.

Затем останется только довести до совпадения.

Также вам поможет режим отладки sip

```
set sip debug on
```

И работа в консоли астериска с более подробным выводом

```
asterisk -rvvvvvvvvv
```